# UDK : UTWeap_RocketLauncher gift CreateInventory: Any idea why this does not work properly?

Tags: udk

I am giving the player an instanced class of UTWeap_RocketLauncher in an instance of UTGame.

```
PlayerPawn.CreateInventory(class'FobikRocketLauncher',false); // Does not work
PlayerPawn.CreateInventory(class'FobikLinkGun',false); // Works
```

Even if I give the original class (eg. UTWeap_RocketLauncher) it does not actually show up. However if I do a "GiveWeapons" cheat, I get it just fine. It also works if I had code it into the map. - But UTWeap_LinkGun works fine either way.

Any ideas? It shows the default ammo amount, and the icon on the HUD.

Comment: You might want to use [UDK Forum](http://forums.epicgames.com/) for your question.

Answer (score 2):

By the `GiveWeapons` cheat, I'm guessing you mean the `AllWeapons` cheat?

`AllWeapons` gives the player the `UTGameContent.UTWeap_RocketLauncher_Content` weapon, which is a subclass of `UTGame.UTWeap_RocketLauncher` that references all the rocket launcher art assets.

So, you'll need to either make `FobikRocketLauncher` "extend" `UTWeap_RocketLauncher_Content` or copy all the art asset references in `UTWeap_RocketLauncher_Content` into `FobikRocketLauncher`.

And the reason the Link Gun works is that it has no such subclass -- `UTGame.UTWeap_LinkGun` has all the link gun art asset references in it.